# How Can I Use shc to Convert Scripts that contain `wget` Into Binaries?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget, binary

I have a bash script that I wish to convert into a binary using shc. It includes the line `wget www.google.com`.

If I run `shc -f myscript.sh` to convert it into `./myscript.sh.x` (the resulting program), nothing happens when it is run.

But when I convert a script that doesn't include the `wget` line it works fine.

Edit as request by larsks:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Downloading Google.com"
wget -O testegoogle.html "www.google.com"
```

What I'm doing is:

1. Save the code as downloadgoogle.sh
2. Run `shc -f downloadgoogle.sh`
3. Execute ./downloadgoogle.sh.x, the resulting file

Nothing happens and the page is not downloaded

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Can you update your question to include an example shell script that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thanks for answer! I edited it including a example and added more informations

Comment: Still [works for me](https://asciinema.org/a/t0Rpm5ZREEymAkQazLalXDp27). Is it exiting with an error code (i.e., check `$?` after the executable exits)?

Comment: It runs with no results. It stays running infinitely. I need to type control + C to to keep using the terminal

Comment: It seems there is a bug in new version of shc. Now it's working after I use `setarch $(uname -m) -R ./downloadgoogle.sh.x`. Thank you for help me larsks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!